# Comparisons across non-nested regressions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, nested-models

I am interested in two non-nested regressions  for the same response,
\begin{eqnarray}
Y  = \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} + \beta_{3}(x_{1}\times x_{2})  +  \epsilon\\
Y  = \beta_{1}’x_{1} + \beta_{2}’x_{3} + \beta_{3}’(x_{1}\times x_{3})  +  \epsilon’
\end{eqnarray}
where $x_{1}$ is binary but $x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$ are both continuous (and correlated). Is there a sensible way to test whether $ \beta_{3} =  \beta_{3}’$? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot build one model with all five terms? (I'm presuming each model is based on the same set of data.)